# What's wrong with this $(this).attr("id").toggle("");

Tags: jquery, syntax, this

What is the proper syntax for toggling the this.id object

> $(this).attr("id").toggle("");

Thanks. Google is surprisingly not helping :(

Comment: what do you mean by 'toggle an object'?

Comment: I have a div with some id (I don't know what it is let's say <div id="x">a link here</div>) when the div with id x is clicked, I want it to be toggled. But I the id might be a, b or c, I don't know that in advance and this cant't use the exact id name. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it is not working is that your first

```
$(this).attr("id")
```

Returns a string, the ID of your item. What you probably want is:

```
$(this).toggle();
```

Answer (score 3):

toggle() is only used for showing/hiding an element, so your question is not entirely clear.

If you want to remove the id, you could use:

```
$(this).attr("id","");
```

Or maybe you want to toggle an element with a specific id:

```
 $("#myid").toggle();
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is what you want to do, Ankur.  You don't need to do all that attr("id","") stuff in order to get a jQuery object that represents the HTML element with the ID you want.

Comment: I will try $("#this.id").toggle(); and $(#this.id).toggle(); - not sure if the "" are required.

Comment: If Ankur is trying to remove the ID of the element, removeAttr('id') is more appropriate than attr('id', "") - in my opinion any way.

Answer (score 0):

This will look for DIVs with any ID attribute and toggle on click:

```
$('div[id]').click(function() {
   $(this).toggle();
}
```